# How to install a system level app on emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-source

I need to install a system app on my device. But I have no access to the device before production. Is there any way to install and test the system app in emulator through Android Studio?

I have a plan to sign it by the platform signature, and install it using adb.

Comment: The emulator and the emulator images that don't contain Google apps are open source but I don't think that the private key used for signing the image is open source, tool. By default all emulator images provided by Google don't allow root access and having the system private key would allow something like root access.

Comment: Thank you @Robert, I still couldn't find any certain solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think there would be any way to embed system apps via Android Studio. It needs to rebuild the image and incorporate the app into the image. I see no other way to include a system app into an AOSP build.